# Eclipse on Mac: The import javafx cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx

I'm using Eclipse 4.10.0 on OSX Mojave 10.14.2 and I get the following error after installing e(fx)clipse from the Eclipse Marketplace:

"The import javafx cannot be resolved"

I'm running Java SE 11.0.1 (jdk-11.0.1).

I tried rebooting, reinstalling everything, installing different versions of Eclipse, Java and asked several people and have run out of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Java 11, JavaFX does not come with the JDK. [Look here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) for instructions on how to install it.

Comment: Correct about the instructions, but you meant Java 11, didn't you?